# Invalid connectionstring for oracle ords docker image

Tags: oracle, docker

I'm trying to connect my oracle database to ords. They are both running in their own docker image. I can easily connect to the database from both sqlcl and datagrip, using a jdbc-url: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCLCDB.localdomain`

As mentioned in the description for the image I have created a volume directory and added a connectionstring txt file:

```
CONN_STRING=dummy/<pwd>@jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/ORCLCDB.localdomain
                
CONN_STRING=dummy/<pwd>@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB.localdomain
```

I've tried several different formats but keep getting the same error message:

```
ERROR: Cannot connect to database please validate CONN_STRING has below shape:
          user/password@hostname:port/service_name
```

[ORDS image](https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:4:115689834374759:::4:P4_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_EULA_ID,P4_BUSINESS_AREA_ID:1183,1183,Oracle%20REST%20Data%20Services%20(ORDS)%20with%20Application%20Express,Oracle%20REST%20Data%20Services%20(ORDS)%20with%20Application%20Express,1,0&cs=3MLIViwoQ80L6lJ_OhtCLhuRTdfFN5EewILcfOmwO-iwHSdJe_zHyIplAmJnBPFemcC5X2fnW94fba4lc85sc3Q)

Answer (score 1):

Follow the documentation

```
CONN_STRING=user/password@host:port/service_name
```

So in your case

```
CONN_STRING=dummy/<pwd>@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB.localdomain
```

The CONN_STRING uses the format of a SQL-NET connection string, the same as you might have in the tnsnames.ora, or when you use direct connect.

```
user/password@host:port/service_name
```

[ORDS in docker](https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:4:10640888575692:::4:P4_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_EULA_ID,P4_BUSINESS_AREA_ID:1183,1183,Oracle%20REST%20Data%20Services%20(ORDS)%20with%20Application%20Express,Oracle%20REST%20Data%20Services%20(ORDS)%20with%20Application%20Express,1,0&cs=3DtiSF3okOCN9gLHvi4gkCuPrwcJG4Ev9VyBKcZVHp-TUp0h4tWSAlj5ClVmETweEJJVH44do2a7ZejGtr_FSeA)

[image]

**Update**

I found also that the documentation states

> user/password credentials require sysdba access, This user will be
> used to install/upgrade APEX and ORDS on you Database.

So I guess there is a contradiction between how the `conn_string` should be set, as the user requiring `sysdba` privileges. The only use who can do that is `sys`, thus try this

```
CONN_STRING=sys/sys_password@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB.localdomain as sysdba
```

Comment: I get the same issue with this format

Comment: one question, can you connect to the ORDS by http ??

Comment: another question, are you using special characters in the password ??

Comment: I can't reach ORDS with http and I don't have any special chars in my pwd

Comment: can you log in by ssh into the docker and check whether ords is up or not ?

Comment: remember that user/password should have sysdba privileges

Comment: @ØysteinSeel, I updated the post. Try this, as the documentation states that only sysdba user can be used for the CONN_STRING

Comment: CONN_STRING=sys/<pwd>@localhost:1521/ORCLCDB.localdomain as sysdba gives: ERROR: CONN_STRING has not set up on containaer varibales.
          user/password@hostname:port/service_name

Comment: that is because the docker is built on multitenant. I would try to remove the sufix localdomain from the ORCLCDB and try again. But the documentation of the docker sucks

Comment: Have the exact same problem. Worst thing is that it was working at some point, both on Windows PC and linux server...

Comment: Yes, you need to double check: 1) network IP (it's easier to use dedicated network and fixed IP for APEX and DB);  2) SYS user to make the installation

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was the password, but it turned out that the image gives the same response when the ORDS container cannot reach the database container. To solve this run

```
docker inspect testapex | grep IPAddress
```

to get the ip address of the database container in the network and then use it in the conn_string.txt file: `CONN_STRING=sys/Welcome1##@123.12.0.2:1521/XEPDB1`

Answer (score 0):

INFO : This container will start a service running ORDS 22.2.0 and APEX 22.1.0.
INFO : CONN_STRING has been found in the container variables file.
ERROR: Cannot connect to database please validate CONN_STRING has below shape:
user/password@hostname:port/service_name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add a blank line before the connection string in the file `conn_string.txt` and use it this way :

```
CONN_STRING="sys/1230123@oracledev:1521/XEPDB1 as sysdba"
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for few days but I've resolved it by using the IP address  of the database container and not localhost or 127.0.0.1. The containers were on the same --network tag but still worked only when I had given the IP address:

`CONN_STRING="sys as sysdba/1230123@<ip_address>:1521/XEPDB1"`

My suggestion to check what is misconfigured or used in your case.